# How to create user session in cakephp 3 by using sql server as its database?

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I already try many way to create user session in cakephp 3 with sql server. 
otherwise I still got the error

Error : `pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit o [CORE\src\Database\Type\BinaryType.php, line 83]`

This is my app.php code :

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'database',
        'handler' => [
            'engine' => 'DatabaseSession',
            'model' => 'CustomerSessions'
        ]
    ]
```

My Model :

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class CustomerSessionsTable extends Table {

  public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->setTable('sessions');
    $this->getPrimaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Customers')
        ->setForeignKey('session_id');
}
```

}

Any recommend please help comment in this question. I really need your help.